# dompdf Blank Page On Large Content

Tags: laravel-4, dompdf

I am using dompdf to print email summaries, these emails are printed sequentially once I have a large email that doesn't fit in the remaining of the page, a new page is created and the content is printed there. **resulting the first page to partially or fully blank** I can't find a solution for that.

Comment: Do you have $debug set to true? Have you looked in the Laravel error logs? Have you looked in your server error logs?

Comment: It would help to see a sample HTML document. The issue could be related to a rendering bug, but it's hard to tell without more detail.

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? If yes, let me know how. I have a similar situation right now.

Comment: @koljanep you need to check the css styles and spaces, if the content does not fit in one page a blank page will be printed. so you need to check the html output before you send it to dompdf

Comment: @MohammadAbuMusa Thanks! I think I found the bug.